# Get a key's value if another key has a certain value

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to get data from an api that returns multiple items when called like the following

```
[{"rate":2.5,"price":123,"userAsset":{"userId":123,"userAssetId":123,"asset":{"assetId":notrelevant}},"isBeingPurchased":notrelevant},
{"rate":2.5,"price":123,"userAsset":{"userId":123,"userAssetId":123,"asset":{"assetId":notrelevant}},"isBeingPurchased":notrelevant}]
```

i want to get userId, userAssetId and price for items with a rate that has a value in a certain range

I tried doing something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import requests
# Get the info from the API
r = requests.get('https://myapi.com/shop')
# Convert the info to a dictionary
data = r.json()

# Get the rates from the dictionary

for value in data:
    rates = print(value['rate'])
    print(rates)

    # Get the info needed later for certain items with a specific rate
    for rates in np.arange(0.1, 2):
        user_asset_id = value['userAsset']['userAssetId']
        user_id = value['userAsset']['userId']
        relative_price = value['price']
        print(user_asset_id, user_id, relative_price)
```

However, this doesn't work and prints out all the userAssetId, userId and price instead of the ones with a specific rate value. I figured it's because of a problem with the for-loops but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: You never use the variable `rate` from `for rates in np.arange(0.1, 2):`.

Comment: In `rates = print(value['rate'])` you're setting `rates` to `None`. `print()` prints its argument, it doesn't return it.

Comment: I think you want `if 0.1 <= value['rate'] <= 2:`

Comment: Thanks! I only noticed now i was setting rates to none. I resolved by setting it to rates = value['rate'] and with the if statement you mentioned